# What is the name of this brass (most likely) instrument?

Tags: instruments, brass, woodwinds

I'm not sure if this is considered an appropriate post, I hope it is but if not, my apologies. I've heard this distinct instrument a couple times. I'm not sure what it is but am really fond of it, and I can't describe it but I think it is probably brass. I only know a smattering about instruments from school but I couldn't remember this one.

I have two songs where I can remember it, I've linked them below at the times I feel this instrument is most clear, unfortunately I think both songs share a bunch of instruments.

Me for You (Spongebob)

Felyne Kitchen (Monster Hunter Something)

Again I am sorry if this is kind of post is not usually appropriate here. Thank you for taking the time to read though.

Comment: These 2 examples feature dozens of instruments. You need to provide a time marker or another example.

Comment: Having discounted several, (vibes, etc.), got it down to the last dozen. Now need to be told when in the recordings it features!

Comment: I think one thing both tracks have in common might be trumpet and clarinet or perhaps a sax (alto?) playing the same line. The trumpet might have a mute

Comment: Bear in mind that none of the instruments may be real. They may have all been taken from a sound module, or from a synth.